# WF for list only?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, workflow

I have watched a lot of video clip about workflow for SharePoint 2013 and it tells me that it is only used for list table only. (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qa1p3qBWfss)

Is Work Flow really only used for object like list only?

Answer (score 0):

That is incorrect.  Site workflows can definitely be created in SharePoint 2013.  I have successfully created and used SharePoint 2013 (Azure) workflows in my sites.

Comment: Can you explain more of your workflow and what object is involve to achieve the result?

Comment: Simply created a new Site Workflow using SharePoint Designer, Here I am using a number of loops and task processes to replicate the functionality provided by the SharePoint 2010 Approval workflow for an entire document library rather than at the individual document level.  Parameters are used to pass in the name of the library to approve all documents in, and the user group responsible for the approval.